# TimescaleDB multiple continuous aggregates not filling up with data

Tags: timescaledb

I'm trying to create several TimescaleDB continuous aggregate tables, like in the examples at the following link, but there is no data in the views when I query them...

https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/continuous-aggregates

Here's my code for creating the continuous aggregate view. I created a 1-hour interval, a 2-hour interval, and a 6-hour interval (i.e. 3 continuous aggregate views, which is apparently allowed in TimescaleDB >= v1.4). I'm using TimescaleDB v1.7.3 in a Docker container on PostgreSQL v11.9.

```
CREATE VIEW time_series_mv_1_hour_interval
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT 
    gateway,
    time_bucket('01:00:00'::interval, timestamp_utc) AS timestamp_utc,
    avg(spm) AS spm,
    avg(hyd::integer) AS hyd
FROM public.time_series
GROUP BY 
    gateway, 
    time_bucket('01:00:00'::interval, timestamp_utc);
```

Here's a picture of my three views "successfully created":
[image]

The underlying table was created as follows, and it's constantly having new IoT data inserted:

```
create table if not exists public.time_series (
    timestamp_utc timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    gateway text NOT NULL,
    spm real NULL,
    hyd bool NULL
    UNIQUE (timestamp_utc, gateway)
);
```

After creating the table, I ran the following to create the TimescaleDB hypertable:
https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#create_hypertable

```
SELECT create_hypertable('public.time_series', 'timestamp_utc');
```

Then I created a smart index on gateway first, then time:

https://blog.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/
https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/schema-management#indexing

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.time_series (gateway, timestamp_utc DESC);
```

***Why is there no data in my newly-created continuous aggregate tables/views?*** I've waited about 16 hours, and still no data.

I ran the following simple query, and no records were returned...

```
SELECT * from time_series_mv_1_hour_interval;
```

Comment: If you will meet this issue again that the caggs are not up-to-date, you can look into `timescaledb_information.continuous_aggregate_stats` [view](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#timescaledb_information-continuous_aggregate_stats) to see if the last job was run and was it successful. Also there might be information in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: drop-**cascade** the existing continuous aggregate views that weren't filling up with rows, and re-create them using the exact same steps...

I wish I knew what was causing the problem the first time around, but at least it's working now.

-Sean